# How to insert multiple images in the Atlas in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, image, html

I have a layer of CROSS SECTIONS (34) and the same number of IMAGES correspondent of each section. In the cross sections layer I have a column named PHOTOS where I defined this field as "ATTACHMENTS > IMAGES" in the attributes form.

[image]

The attribute table for the CROSS SECTIONS is this:

[image]

I made a ATLAS of it and I would like to see the images of each CROSS SECTIONS when I run the atlas. I tried to insert this HTML code:

```
<body style="font-family:calibri;"> <p>  <span style="color:#0c0002;font-weight:bold;"
>CROSS SECTIONS </p>  SECTION NUMBER =  <span style="color:#d91e3d;font-weight:bold;"
 > [% "Cross-Sect"%]</span> </p> <img src="CS19_River_Cross-section_Photo.jpeg"  width="600" height="600" > </p> </body>
```

to insert the images but it does not work as you can see in the image below:

[image]

Can you please tell me, how can I do this?
I´m using QGIS 3.4

Comment: There are two ways to add an image to the print composer. The first is using HTML in an HTML item. The second is using a Picture item. Try the second method.

Answer (score 5):

Just use expression to link the attribute as a source for your image like you do in case `CROSS SECTIONS` attribute `[% "Cross-Sect"%]`

In your case use:

```
<img src=[% "PHOTOS"%]  width="600" height="600" >
```

This retrieve the string (path to photo on your drive) from `PHOTOS` attribute for atlas feature.

If you can't see image even with manually inserted source, check if the path is correct. Use full path or relative path to QGIS project. Also check the path in the `PHOTOS` attribute

Comment: I notice the spaces in path in your _PHOTOS_ attribute, remove them.

Comment: Oto, it real works. I removed all the " spaces " in my folders and image name also. Path: D:\Photos\Image1